# c# async socket program.Callback for receive data is not executed

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I followed this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx for async socket programming.

Else part of ReceiveCallback func is never called. When there is any data, it is received in if(bytesRead >0) part. In if loop, to get the rest of the data, BeginReceive is called again. But callback for this is not received at all.

```
 private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
        try {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0) {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            } else {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1) {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using TCP? In that case, `EndReceive` will only return 0 when the connection is closed - so this code will only work if the other side closes the connection after sending all of the data. I'm pretty sure that's not actually what you want :) And please, consider using the newer Task-based asynchronous APIs - they're much easier to use, especially with `await`. And in any case, why not use TcpListener/TcpClient? Raw sockets are even trickier than just using those.

Comment: @Luaan Can you please share a sample code which has implemented newer task based async apis? And can u explain the reason why you want me to try TcpClient rather than sockets. I'm new to this. So a bit of explanation would help. Thanks

Comment: I've got some samples on https://github.com/Luaancz/Networking - it's not production ready, but it should be a decent starting point. The reason to use TcpClient instead of sockets is simple - sockets are even lower level than TcpClient. TcpClient exposes the logical stream that TCP is, rather than working with the general Send/Receive methods (which are also used for e.g. UDP, which is message-based, rather than stream-based).